# Python: Remote-Debugging with Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remote-debugging

**Versions**:

Windows (10), Chrome-(89.0.4389.128), ChromeDriver-(89.0.4389.23), Selenium-(3.141.0)

**Issue**:

I'm currently have some issues with the remote-debugger option with ChromeDriver/Selenium. I'm able to open a new Chrome page and navigate to wherever I'd like by using:

```
C:\Users\test>chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\temp\test"
```

However, when I try and run the code below, nothing happens until I exit the page and get a:

'*SessionNotCreatedException:Unable to receive message from renderer*'.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

driver_path = 'D:\Anything\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=chrome_options)

print(driver.title)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. If I left out any important info I'd be happy to answer.

Side question: do the Chrome Developer Tools need be enabled in order to use remote-debugging?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('remote-debugging-port=9222')
```

You may also need to escape the back slash in the path as: `D:\\Anything\\chromedriver.exe`

This is tested to work with Chrome>=90.